# How would I make my score go up based on how many things are dodged

Tags: coronasdk

The idea of my game is that my penguin dodges iceblocks how would i get the score to go up based on the amount of dodged iceblocks?

Comment: What happens to the ice blocks when the penguin dodges them?

Answer (score 1):

If the iceblock is falling from above, create a sensor at the bottom of the scene, if the iceblock hits the penguin, destroy the iceblock, if it hits the sensor, add points